# In Microfrontend, how to expose application routes from individual micro-frontends and integrate them into the main application using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm attempting to integrate the exposed routes from a separate application into my main application, but I'm encountering challenges and feeling uncertain about the process. Let me share my code to illustrate how I'm currently approaching this.

I've developed two applications – one being the product application.

1] Product application (react)
I've defined routes within my app.tsx file."

- app.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import routes from './config/routes';
import Productpage from './page/productpage';
import Homepagepage from './page/homepage';
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter >
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Homepagepage />} />
          <Route path='/product' element={<Productpage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

- webpack.config.js
  This is my web configuration file for the product application, and I'm exposing this application on port 3004 for the container application.

```
//home-app/webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const path = require('path');
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index",
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 3004,  // port 3001 for header-app
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            transpileOnly: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
                use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'product',
            filename: 'product.js',
            library: { type: 'var', name: 'product' },
            exposes: {
                './product': './src/App.tsx',
            },
            remotes: {},
            shared: {
                ...deps,
                react: {
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps.react,
                    eager: true,
                },
                'react-dom': {
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
                    eager: true,
                },
                'react-router-dom': {
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps['react-router-dom'],
                    eager: true,
                },
            }
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3004/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    target: "web",
};
```

2] Main application (react)

- webpack.config.js
  This is my web configuration file for the main application, and I'm consuming the expose application on port 3005.

```
//home-app/webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index",
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 3005,  // port 3001 for header-app
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            transpileOnly: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
                use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'microapps-container',
            filename: 'microapps-container.js',
            remotes: {
                "product": "product@http://localhost:3004/product.js",
            },
            exposes: {},
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3005/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    target: "web",
};
```

- app.tsx

Here i'm confused how can i use the route's of expose application here."

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import './App.css';
const Producteapp = React.lazy(() => import("product/product"))

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}><Producteapp /></Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```